# iOS logic - Adding sequential subviews constructed programmatically with proper coordinates

Tags: ios, xamarin

ORIGINAL TITLE: iOS logic - Adding a view with its child elements in Xamarin

I'm not completely sure how to word this question so I will do the best I can.

You know how an app like Groupon lists its offers? Or how the Facebook app, has dynamically produced sections in the minifeed - squares containing child elements like the profile image view, name, post content etc.  What is the logic behind this?

What I've tried doing putting a content view in the designer and laying out the elements i want in this content view section, and then recreating content views programmtically with the child elements from the view i made in the designer.  Is this the proper approach?  Could someone enlighten me on the standard logic of achieving this?

EDIT:

I figured out that what I was really trying to ask was: What is the best way to build a subview (with subviews of its own, including an image, labels, textfield, etc) programmatically, and then dynamically add copies of it - one below the next - to a scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what I was trying to do, add one view after another.  I figured out the dimensions of where the elements should be in the view by making it in the designer and getting the coordinates from there.  I created a custom UIView class:

```
public class FestivalSquareView : UIView
{
    public UIImageView festivalImage { get; set; }
    public UILabel nameLabel { get; set; }
    public UILabel locationLabel { get; set; }
    public UILabel dateLabel { get; set; }
    public UITextView descriptionText { get; set; }

    public static int HEIGHT = 270;

    public FestivalSquareView ()
    {

    }
    public FestivalSquareView (string image, string name, string location,
                               string date, string description)
    {
        setImage (image);
        setName (name);
        setLocation (location);
        setDate (date);
        setDescription (description);
    }
    public void setImage(string imageLoc)
    {
        festivalImage = new UIImageView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 320, 177));

        festivalImage.Image = UIImage.FromFile (imageLoc);
    }
    public void setName(string name)
    {

        nameLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(20,129,150,21));
        nameLabel.Text = name;  
        nameLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 15f);
        nameLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;    

    }
    public void setLocation(string location)
    {
        locationLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(20,148,100,21));
        locationLabel.Text = location;  
        locationLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 13f);
        locationLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;    
    }  
    public void setDate(string date)
    {
        dateLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF (195, 148, 105, 21));
        dateLabel.Text = date;
        dateLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        dateLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 13f);
        dateLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
    }
    public void setDescription(string description)
    {
        descriptionText = new UITextView (new RectangleF (20, 185, 280, 75));
        descriptionText.Text = description;
    }
    public void buildView(float y)
    {

        this.Frame = new RectangleF (0, y, 320, 270);

        this.AddSubview (festivalImage);
        this.AddSubview (nameLabel);
        this.AddSubview (locationLabel);
        this.AddSubview (dateLabel);
        this.AddSubview (descriptionText);
    }


}
```

I put a scroll view into my ViewController using the designer, connected it, constructed my custom UIView above, set the Y cooardinate in buildView, and added it to the scrollview

And then I calculated the next Y coordinate using

```
next.buildView (prev.Frame.Y + prev.Frame.Size.Height);
festivalScrollView.AddSubView(next);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using UITableView and/or UICollectionView to host the views.